# sql linter for mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, unit-testing, testing

I'm building an application that generates a lot of sql queries. Some of them are complex (to me) and writing good tests is tricky.

As a sanity test it would be nice to run the generated SQL queries through a linter. So, the tests wouldn't actually run/execute the queries on the database, but it would parse the query and make sure it looks valid.

I realize this isn't a great test, but I figure it would be fast, and my PHP linter has helped me catch a lot of issues, so if I could build this into unit tests it seems like a fast way to catch some low hanging fruit.

I'm working in PHP and MySql (on linux) so I'd prefer a solution for that environment but I'll take what I can get. Maybe it will point me in the right direction.

Comment: Try [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Several possibilities (I confess - the only one I'm personally familiar with is SQL Fiddle):

- SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/
- MySql Test Framework:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqltest/2.0/

- Google Test Framework:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqltest/2.0/en/unit-tests-google-test.html

- myTAP:

https://github.com/hepabolu/mytap

Since you're using PHP, you should probably also look at PHPUnit:

- http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/database.html

'Hope that helps ... at least a little

Comment: There's some interesting stuff in there, some of it I knew about but some of it I didn't. I don't think any of it looks like what I was asking for, but I'll look into them. Who knows, maybe I'll run into something that's so cool I won't want/need a linter anymore.